# InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2

Tags: java

Есть файл из которого я считаю пути к файлам, заношу в список и дальше считаю сколько в этих путях файлов.

```
String pathToFile = "D:/tt/dump.txt";
ArrayList<String> list = new MyFileReader().read(pathToFile);
for(String s1 : list) {
     System.out.println(Files.walk(Paths.get(s1))
         .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
         .map(Path::toFile)
         .collect(Collectors.toList()).size());
}
```

выскакивает данная ошибка
входящий файл:

```
D:/example
D:/MyProgram
D:/otherfiles
```

при первом обращении кидается ошибка :

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: D:/example
```

но если код завернуть в `try catch` на первую строку кидается ошибка но все последующие нормально отрабатывают.
и так на любую первую строку которую я введу.

```
 public class MyFileReader {

        public ArrayList<String> read(String File) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
            ArrayList<String> listOfPaths = new ArrayList<>();
            BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(File));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufRead.readLine()) != null) {
                listOfPaths.add(line);
            }
            bufRead.close();
            return listOfPaths;
        }
    }
```

вопрос: Что мне сделать чтоб первая запись нормально отрабатывала?

Comment: покажите **MyFileReader**

Comment: @MikhailVaysman добавил

Comment: а если захардкодить список, то будет ошибка?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman если захардкодить руками то все норм)

Comment: значит проблема в самом файле, может там какой-то невидимый символ или что-то с кодировкой.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Вы оказались правы.

Comment: @user257569 поди файл в UTF-8 с BOM?

Answer (score 1):

Напишите так:

```
String pathToFile = "D:\\tt\\dump.txt";
```

так должно сработать. Символ разделитель пути задается константой `File.separator` и может отличаться в разных платформах. Обратный слэш воспринимается и в Windows и Unix системах. Двойной обратный слэш применяется для экранирования символа `backslash`

Comment: нет( не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Переделайте аргумент для метода read в тип `File`, вы все равно его пробрасываете в FileReader, у которого есть конструктор соответствующего типа:

```
public FileReader(File file) throws FileNotFoundException
```

А когда будете передавать ему в качестве параметра File, то скормите обработанную строчку. Например, вот так:

```
Paths.get("d:\\some\\path\\somefile.txt")
```

Вариант с рефакторингом:

```
public class MyFileReader {

    public List<String> read(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        final List<String> listOfPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        final BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufRead.readLine()) != null) {
            listOfPaths.add(line);
        }
        bufRead.close();

        return listOfPaths;
    }
}
```

пример использования класса:

```
List<String> rows = new MyFileReader().read(
    Paths.get("d:\\some\\path\\somefile.txt")
)
```